# Do you receive interest on Peercoin if you use an online wallet?

Tags: e-wallet, proof-of-stake, peercoin

I know Peercoin is proof-of-stake, but if I use an online wallet, will I receive any of the coins generated for my stake? Or do I have to have to download a desktop wallet?

Comment: Do you have a particular online wallet in mind? Different ones might work in different ways.

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/36205/18196

Comment: @Nate Eldredge, no, I don't have a specific one in mind, I was more wondering if there are any which are definitely known to give you the peercoins you've staked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a web wallet that holds your private keys, then it is certainly possible that the service is staking your coins for you, but this may or may not be a feature that the developers of the particular web wallet have implemented. It is also possible that the web wallet creators take the stake as a payment for their service, which I hope the service would be transparent about.

If the web wallet is a watch-only wallet, then it cannot stake for you. [[1]](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/36205/18196)